# Java: How to reconstruct an unknown class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have  a class that instantiates a generic object that can be any one of the subclasses of a specific class:

```
abstract class Sport;
class Basketball extends Sport {
    Basketball (Team teamA, Team teamB) { /*set sport rules*/ }
}
class Soccer extends Sport {
    Soccer (Team teamA, Team teamB) { /*set sport rules*/ }
}

class Match {
    Sport s;

    Match (Sport y) { this.s = y; }

    void playMatch ();
}
```

What happens is i would like to be able to reset the object in my method by calling its constructor:

```
void playMatch () {
    this.s = new /*class of s*/();
    /*do stuff with s*/
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: You want `method` to construct an object based on the type of the object currently stored in `s`?

Comment: `super` is a keyword, you cannot use this as a class name...

Comment: Please post only real code, not sort-of, kind-of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your **s** constructor has no parameter, you can call:

```
s.getClass().newInstance()
```

Else, if you know it's constructor's parameters,

```
Constructor ctor = s.getClass().getConstructor(TypeA.class, TypeB.class, etc...);
S sInstance = (S)ctor.newInstance(typeAValue, typeBValue, etc...Value);
```

Else, you can use [Objenesis](http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/), which can generate any kind of class you need, but be aware that by using that method, you can get an object without any constructors being called, which can be dangerous. You have to tell objenesis to call your constructor manually, but then again, you must know the parameters it needs.

---

But i don't understand your code... is it java, or pseudocode?

---

Now that you posted some real code, I seriously wouldn't recommand you to use this answer. In fact, this is the way you can instanciate objects from unknown classes, but in your case, you shouldn't have to do that.

I recommand you to add a `reset()` method to your `Sport` class.
Instanciating objects using reflection is dangerous; if your constructor parameters changes, you won't notice at compile-time. It's also slow at runtime, although it's not a big matter these days... unless you call it 1000 times per seconds.

It also enables you to implements an [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) later so you can follow the status of your sports. There's also alot of other things it would prevent you to do...

You really shouldn't do that.

Comment: _"But i don't understand your code... is it java, or pseudocode?"_ ...Yes